# Trying to web scraping with nodeJS and cheerIO

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, cheerio

I'm trying to use web scraping with nodeJS and cheerIO, but I'm not able to get the HTML content.
I tried with .html() function and is not resolving it, it says that is not a function.

This is the code where I'm trying to obtain the data from the web page:

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const request = require('request');

const test_data = {}

test_data.getHouses = async () => {
    const $doc = await request({
        uri: 'https://es-l.airbnb.com/s/San-Sebasti%C3%A1n--Spain/homes?tab_id=all_tab&refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fhomes&query=San%20Sebasti%C3%A1n%2C%20Spain&place_id=ChIJFf5oO_6vUQ0RSUaGlFnFPuQ&source=structured_search_input_header&search_type=search_query',
        transform: body => cheerio.load(body)
    });
    console.log($doc);
}
```

This is the request object output.

```
Request {
  _events: [Object: null prototype] { pipe: [Function] },
  _eventsCount: 1,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  uri: Url {
    protocol: 'https:',
    slashes: true,
    auth: null,
    host: 'es-l.airbnb.com',
    port: 443,
    hostname: 'es-l.airbnb.com',
    hash: null,
    search: '?tab_id=all_tab&refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fhomes&query=San%20Sebasti%C3%A1n%2C%20Spain&place_id=ChIJFf5oO_6vUQ0RSUaGlFnFPuQ&source=structured_search_input_header&search_type=search_query',
    query: 'tab_id=all_tab&refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fhomes&query=San%20Sebasti%C3%A1n%2C%20Spain&place_id=ChIJFf5oO_6vUQ0RSUaGlFnFPuQ&source=structured_search_input_header&search_type=search_query',
    pathname: '/s/San-Sebasti%C3%A1n--Spain/homes',
    path: '/s/San-Sebasti%C3%A1n--Spain/homes?tab_id=all_tab&refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fhomes&query=San%20Sebasti%C3%A1n%2C%20Spain&place_id=ChIJFf5oO_6vUQ0RSUaGlFnFPuQ&source=structured_search_input_header&search_type=search_query',
    href: 'https://es-l.airbnb.com/s/San-Sebasti%C3%A1n--Spain/homes?tab_id=all_tab&refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fhomes&query=San%20Sebasti%C3%A1n%2C%20Spain&place_id=ChIJFf5oO_6vUQ0RSUaGlFnFPuQ&source=structured_search_input_header&search_type=search_query'
  },
  transform: [Function: transform],
  readable: true,
  writable: true,
  _qs: Querystring {
    request: [Circular],
    lib: { formats: [Object], parse: [Function], stringify: [Function] },
    useQuerystring: undefined,
    parseOptions: {},
    stringifyOptions: {}
  },
  ............................
}
```

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

The `request` module isn't by default a Promise. You would have to put a wrapper on top of it in order to promisify it and use it in the async fashion you want. As a result, it is simply returning to you the actual `Request` object instead of the body you want.

Use this code instead to get the body:

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const request = require('request');

const test_data = {}

test_data.getHouses = () => {
    const $doc = request({
        uri: 'https://es-l.airbnb.com/s/San-Sebasti%C3%A1n--Spain/homes?tab_id=all_tab&refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fhomes&query=San%20Sebasti%C3%A1n%2C%20Spain&place_id=ChIJFf5oO_6vUQ0RSUaGlFnFPuQ&source=structured_search_input_header&search_type=search_query',
        transform: body => cheerio.load(body)
    }, function(err, response, body) {
      console.log(body);
    });
}

test_data.getHouses();
```

Comment: This worked, but now I'm getting an undefined body. I used the next line const options = {
    headers: {'user-agent': 'node.js'}} for accesing the server, but I'm unable to watch the HTML code. Any suggestion? Thanks! @Harvard Pan